# Django rest framework add image with react and axios

Tags: reactjs, django

I am trying to make a form where a user uploads a post which is just a picture. I am using django rest framework for api and react for frontend.

```
const formData = new FormData()

  const savePost = () => {
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_post/', formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    })
  }

const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])
      formData.append("image", e.target.files[0]);
  }

<form onSubmit={savePost}>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But when I press submit a new instance is added but the image is just `/media/` without the actual image.